# Update a Joined Table with SQLAlchemy Core

Tags: python, mysql, join, sqlalchemy, inner-join

I have a MySQL db with tables set up like this:

```
Table1      Table2
------      ------
  id          id, fk to Table1.id
  name        name
```

I want to update `Table1` and set `Table1.id = Table2.id` if `Table1.name = Table2.name`. Or, in SQL:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.name = t2.name
SET t1.id = t2.id;
```

How can I accomplish an equivalent statement using the SQLAlchemy Core API?

I can call `table1.join(table2, table1.c.name == table2.c.name)` to create the join, but how can I update this joined table?

Answer (score 5):

```
upd = table1.update()\
    .values(id=table2.c.id)\
    .where(table1.c.name == table2.c.name)
```

should do it, but if you really have all those foreign keys, you might get errors doing such updates.

Comment: I'm getting `"Unknown column 'table2.id' in 'field list'"`, so it doesn't appear to be inferring the join.

Comment: Please check for typos etc.