# update joined table using sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, sqlite, join, sqlalchemy, sql-update

I want to update the values in a table dependent on values in another table.

I have 2 tables:

_LOCATIONR: _id, _status, _uuid

LOCATIONR: _id, _version and some userdata

_status shall be set to 1 if _version=0, _uuid="42" and _id=1

i use python with sqlalchemy, database is sqlite

```
sc#table LOCATIONR
sc2#table _LOCATIONR
version = 0
uuid = "42"
id = 1
statement = sc2.update().
                where(and_(
                    sc2.c._id == id,
                    sc2.c._id == sc.c._id,
                    sc.c._version == version,
                    sc2.c._uuid == uuid))
r = statement.execute({"_status": 1, "_id": id, "_uuid": uuid})
```

Log:

```
2016-03-09 22:08:45,059 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE "_LOCATIONR" SET _uuid=?, _status=?, _id=? FROM "LOCATIONR" WHERE "_LOCATIONR"._id = ? AND "_LOCATIONR"._id = "LOCATIONR"._id AND "LOCATIONR"._version = ? AND "_LOCATIONR"._uuid = ?
2016-03-09 22:08:45,059 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('42', 1, 1, 1, 0, '42')
2016-03-09 22:08:45,060 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Everytime I execute the above code sqlalchemy makes a rollback.
The errors occur only if the whereclause references sc
but due to those links it should be ok
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/HH7Rw65kypA

[Update a Joined Table with SQLAlchemy Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274133/update-a-joined-table-with-sqlalchemy-core)

Comment: In sqlite this sql statement works: UPDATE _LOCATIONR SET _status=1 WHERE _uuid="42" AND _id=1 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LOCATIONR WHERE _LOCATIONR._id=LOCATIONR._id AND LOCATIONR._version=0);
COMMIT;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
statement = (sc2
             .update()
             .where(and_(sc2.c._id == id,
                         sc2.c._uuid == uuid,
                         exists().where(and_(sc2.c._id == sc.c._id,
                                             sc.c._version == version))))
```

works.