# Sqlalchemy + Postgres - multiple values update

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I neet to make a statement similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797608/update-multiple-rows-in-same-query-using-postgresql/18799497#18799497), but in Python Sqlalchemy. This is the code I'm trying to write:

```
def _update(
            self,
            table: sqlalchemy.Table,
            df: pd.DataFrame,
            autocommit: bool = False):
            """
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['id', 'values'])
            """

        # with new_values(id, values) as (
        #     values
        #     ('id1', '{0.1,0.0}'::real[]),
        #     ('id2', '{0.0,0.1}'::real[])
        # )
        # update schema.table as t set
        #     values = new_values.values
        #     from new_values
        # where t.id = new_values.id

        stmt = above_comments_to_sqlalchemy(df)

        response = self.session.execute(stmt)
        if autocommit:
            self.session.commit()
        return response
```

Comment: Please specify your problem, your issue isn't cleared...

Comment: Just added more context

Comment: You'd have to combine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543223/how-do-you-express-a-multi-table-update-update-from-in-sqlalchemy-orm or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274133/update-a-joined-table-with-sqlalchemy-core (depending on using ORM or Core) with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858291/values-clause-in-sqlalchemy.

Comment: Thank you @IljaEverilä ! Tomorrow I'll give it a try

Answer (score -1):

Following the docs: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html

1) Create an engine with `create_engine()`

2) Open a connection with `connect()`

3) execute a query using `execute()`

For example:

```
engine = create_engine();
connection = engine.connect();

queryString = 'UPDATE <TableName> SET...'

connection.execute(queryString);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my point is on doing the same statements with the sqlalchemy interface, without having to write my query string, such as:

df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
table.update().where(table.c.id == df[id]).values(df.to_dict())

Comment: You understand that in order to do so you need to open a connection to the database right?

Comment: You could use the ORM of sql alchemy to do so. see: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#connecting